# images are inserted to excel file by Apache POI ,but they are not shown

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an gwt web application on linux .In server side ,I tried to insert some images to   excel file by Apache poi 3.10.

I got inputstream of image files from db and send it to existing excel file .
the code is:

```
 Drawing patriarch = null;

 private void addImages(InputStream in, HSSFWorkbook requestReport, HSSFSheet sheet, int row, int  col) throws IOException {
    CreationHelper helper = requestReport.getCreationHelper();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    int pictureIndex = requestReport.addPicture(bytes, HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
  in.close();
    if (patriarch == null) {
        patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    }
    anchor.setAnchorType(2);
    anchor.setRow1(row);
    anchor.setCol1(col);
    Picture picture = patriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);

    picture.resize();
    picture.setLineStyle(HSSFPicture.LINESTYLE_DASHDOTGEL);
}
```

In this case that I get Inputstream from DB, I get NoSuchElementException on  picture.resize().

On the other hand if I use image from disk to insert, there is no error and image is not shown.

in = new FileInputStream("/test.jpeg")

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue with accessing the inputstream from a remote location.  My input stream is not empty since I can see the raw data when I debug.  How did you fix your database streaming issue?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disk image is not shown because you don't set the second column and row in your anchor. You should add:

```
anchor.setRow2(row + 1);
anchor.setCol2(col + 1);
```

I don't know what's the reason why the input stream from your DB gives an error. The error suggests that the input stream is empty (doesn't contain data), but the reason cannot be determined from your post.